# c++ line from file stored in char array

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to be able to read a full line into a character array using a function.

example input text is:

```
Schmidt, Helga
Alvarez, Ruben
Zowkowski, Aaron
Huang, Sun Lee
Einstein, Beverly
```

However, im not sure how to read a full line of characters into the array. I know the delimiter for >> is whitespace, but I'm not sure if I change that delimiter to '\n' if it'd work?

```
void buildList(char (*array)[25], ifstream& inputFile){
    string line;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        getline(inputFile, line);
        array[i] = line.c_str();     
}
```

Currently this only reads either a last name or first name into my input instead of the whole line. I'm not sure how I can go about changing this. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeZ that returns a string, not char* though.

Comment: Try using getline. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) is how.
You can always convert string to char* array.

Comment: @WorldDominator It takes a string as an output parameter, to be precise. And of course you can always get the `cstr` of any string.

Comment: I really would recommend you use the `std::string` version of `getline`, but if you absolutely insist on not, there are versions that are members of the streams that work with a raw `char` buffer [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

Comment: @Hulk I just edited my code to what I believe you recommended but the compiler gives me the issue of "incompatible types in assignment of 'const char*' to 'char [25]'". I'm not sure if c_str helps me.

Comment: The c_str is only a pointer to the raw buffer inside the string - it gets destroyed when the string goes out of scope and is destructed, so you'd need to copy it's contents before that.

Comment: @WorldDominator `c_str()` does not help you.  You'd need someplace to store the pointer (and you don't have any pointer that will outlive the function call) and some means of extending the lifetime of the string.  You could read the line into a `string`, then use `std::string::copy` to move it into your arrays, but there's really no point in it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you definitely want to use `std::string` here.  Once you
do that, you can use `std::getline`:

```
std::vector<std::string>
buildList( istream& input )
{
    std::vector<std::string> results;
    std::string line
    while ( std::getline( input, line ) ) {
        results.push_back( line );
    }
}
```

This will make for much simpler and more robust code.

If you have to use such a broken interface, there is a member
function `getline`:

```
for ( int i = 0; i != 5; ++ i ) {
    input.getline( array[i], maxLength );
}
```

Also: a function should *never* take an `std::ifstream&` as
argument (unless it is going to open or close the file).  An
`std::istream&` should be used.

Comment: Thank you James! the input.getline worked splendid. My professor said we should use char ** for this assignment so that's why I did it this way. Also, he has not gone over vectors yet. I'll keep the istream& in mind.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where is the memory allocated for `array[]`?  ie. what set up all the `char *` in the array?

Comment: @WorldDominator I susspected something along these lines.  Logically, I can't believe that someone would introduce you to declarations along the lines of `char (*array)[25]` (a pointer to an array of 25 `char`, or a pointer to the first of many such) before teaching you `std::vector` and `std::string`, but I keep seeing it.

Comment: @JoeZ At the call site.  My guess is that he has something like `char data[5][25];`, and passes `data` as an argument.  What gets me, however: doing this right (and if that's his data declaration, he's done it right) requires knowing some of the more arcane aspects of the C++ type system.  It would be one of the last things I'd teach.

Comment: @JamesKanze To be honest, the teacher is very poor at teaching and hasnt been in class for 2 weeks now. I've learned as much as I would have if he had been here though. He said we had to initialize the array to array[5][25] in our main function (I'm using header files). So that's why I passed char (*array) [25].

Comment: @WorldDominator And you were able to figure out the type of the argument?  I more or less figured out the type at the call site from the function declaration (and the fact that you looped 5 times), but I would hardly consider it obvious.  And of course, because it is a C style array, you can't use it as a return value (which would be the "cleanest" way to handle an out parameter), and you end up with a really awkward declaration in the function.

Comment: Good grief!  That was questionable style even back in the 80s!  It introduces control coupling between the caller and callee, for example.  The inner loop in the callee has to "know" there are 5 things, and the caller has to "know" to allocate 5 things, for example.  And what happens next when you need to handle 6 things, or worse, N things where N is discovered at run time?

Comment: @JoeZ He _could_ declare it `char (&array)[5][25]`.  That way, if any of the numbers changed, the code would no longer compile.  (But as you might guess, I prefer `std::vector<std::string>`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Maybe I'm the one to blame for interpreting what he wanted us to do differently? I don't know, but I need to work on my insersort algorithm for a different function in this same program. What a headache. I don't know why he recommended using a char**, it seems like it causes more trouble than it 'helps'.

Comment: @WorldDominator It definitely does.  And if you have a `char array[5][25]`, you cannot pass it to a `char**`; to use a `char**`, you'd need a `char *array[5]`, with each of the pointers pointing to a `char [25]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this-

```
void buildList(char (*array)[25], ifstream& inputFile){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        std::inputFile.getline(array[i],50);
}
```

The second parameter of `getline` is the maximum number of characters to write to the character array.

Comment: if I use getline I get the error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, char [25])'

Comment: The function is declared in `std` namespace.

Comment: I'm using namespace std though. Isn't it because instead of a string, I used a char[25]?

Comment: Oh yes, I overlooked that, I'll just edit the answer.

Comment: This is completely wrong.  The `getline` that takes a `char*` is a member of `std::istream`, and must use the member syntax in the call.  It also requires a maximum length as a second argument.

Comment: Interesting edit.  He declares the output arrays to have a size of 25, and you specify a maximum input length of 50.

Comment: Yes, there are are two versions of `getline`, I used the one for `std::string`, but I just edited it now, thanks.